# http301 redirect from non-www to www not working anymore

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I've been using this code for years. However it looks like that a few days ago it stopped working as far as folders are concerned.

```
RewriteEngine on

#convert everything to www
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

So, to wrap it up:

http://foo.com/blah.php -> http://www.foo.com/blah.php

HOWEVER http://foo.com/bar/ -> http://www.foo.com AND NOT http://www.foo.com/bar/

I'm using http://www.redirect-checker.org/index.php to thoroughly check what's going on, and all I see is a normal http301 redirect. The only thing I notice is that it's a wrong redirect.

I tried to delete everything from .htaccess but the lines of code I pasted above, but the result is the same.

Could it be that my (shared plan) hosting company changed something in Apache's internal configuration?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is `/bar/` a real directory? Does `/bar/` has a `.htaccess` as well.

Comment: /bar/ is a real directory. Yes it does contain a .htaccess. I noticed that if I remove that file (or leave it empty), the redirect works. However as soon as I add just RewriteEngine On, the redirect stop working.

Comment: Yes that's correct behavior. Putting `RewriteEngine On` there blocks all the rule from parent .htaccess

Comment: Actually it's followed by a RewriteOptions inherit, and then by the Rewrite rules that are specific to that folder.

Comment: Sure: http://pastebin.com/Tw9aMbSW  However it happens the same for every other folder (with different lines of code into them).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is that by using `Inherit` in each sub-directory this `www` adding rule sets `$1` relative to that sub-directory only. Use this rule instead in **parent .htaccess**:

```
RewriteEngine on

#convert everything to www
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

Comment: I see the issue now. Your solution works great, thank you so much!